# Regular expression to allow all except few

Tags: asp.net

The textbox has max length of 50 chars. and user should be able to enter any text except these 4 chars -

> < > ' @

.

Please help me with the expression?

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revReason" ControlToValidate="txtReason"
 runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
 ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9_,~`!#$%^&*()\[\]{}\|+=:;./?\s-]{1,50}$" >
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regular expression `[^\<\>\'\@]`

```
ValidationExpression="[^\<\>\'\@]"
```

Comment: Just using that one gave invalid for every char. so I had to use           `ValidationExpression="[^\<\>\'\@]{1,50}"` to make it work